# Error in using startActivity

Tags: android

I have the following code that crashes upon click. When startActivity(...) is commented out, it does not crash (but does not work). But the Activity is empty! I'm clueless as to what's going on. Taking out the Bundle does not work.

Anyone have any ideas?

In RSSReader.java

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id)
 {
     Log.i(tag,"item clicked! [" + feed.getItem(position).getTitle() + "]");

     Intent itemintent = new Intent(this,ShowDescription.class);

     Bundle b = new Bundle();
     b.putString("title", feed.getItem(position).getTitle());
     b.putString("description", feed.getItem(position).getDescription());
     b.putString("link", feed.getItem(position).getLink());
     b.putString("pubdate", feed.getItem(position).getPubDate());

     itemintent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.INTENT", b);

     startActivity(itemintent);
 }
```

ShowDescription.java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
public class ShowDescription extends Activity 
{
}
```

Comment: First, when you have a crash situation, you should always include the stack trace so we can get an idea of what the error is.  Second, is there a reason you're putting values in the bundle rather than directly into the intent?

Comment: also include your manifest file - the part where you define your activity

Answer (score 1):

I think you at least need the following in your activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have added the ShowDescription activity to the Manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to declare the second activity in your manifest like so:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light">
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".ShowDescription" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

and also make sure it's a valid activity as Sid said:

```
import android.app.Activity;
public class ShowDescription extends Activity 
{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //grab your Bundle stuff if you want to handle it that way:
        String title = savedInstanceState.getString("title");
        //etc.

        //Inflate/create your layouts here and set the contentview.
        setContentView(showDescLayout);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Somehow, some junk got inserted in my manifest. I've fixed it up.